# Mixing embedded bibliographical entries with ones from database.bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am in the unpleasant situation to have some references that I would like to cite embedded in the source file as `\bibitem` entries, and some others in a `database.bib` file.

Is it possible to mix them together in a single References section at the end of the document?

Comment: No, sorry. Only in two distinct references section.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.